# If $f$ is continuous and $f[a,b]$ contains only finitely many real numbers, then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and that $f[a,b]$ contains only finitely many real numbers. Prove that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

Comment: An idea: use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: $f([a,b])$ is also connected since $[a,b]$ is connected . But if you have only finitely value then contradiction

Answer (score 0):

The continuous image of an interval ($[a,b]$ is an interval) is connected, that is, you cannot separate the image as a union of disjoint non-empty open subsets. Since there are only finitely many points, there must only be one point, since $\Bbb{R}$ has the property that any two distinct points can be separated by disjoint non-empty open sets.  Conclude $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

By Extreme Value Theorem we have that there exist $m, M \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $m \le f(x) \le M$ and by Intermediate Value Theorem we have that for each $y$ s.t. $m\le y \le M$ there exists a $x$ s.t. $f(x) = y$. So therefore: $\text{Im } f = [m,M]$ and obviously as $m\not = M$ there are infinitely many real numbers in the image, which violates the condition. Hence we can conclude that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is not constant; then there are $x_1, x_2\in[a, b]$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Now take any $y$ in between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$. Then because $f$ is continuous, so by Intermediate Value Theorem, there must exist some $c$ in between $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(c)=y$. So $y\in f[a, b]$. But there are infinitely many such $y$'s in between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ which contradicts the fact that $f[a, b]$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

$[a,b]$ is compact in R. So $f$ takes it to a compact set in the co-domain, $i.e$ $f[a,b]$ is compact (closed and bounded). But given that $f[a,b]$ contains only finite number of points and that is a closed and bounded set; very fine. For not to lose continuity of $f$, $f[a,b]$ must be a singleton set. $f[a,b]$ must be a singleton set means $f$ is constant function.